# Visual studio 2017 debugger not working for core 2

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I am using Core 2 Asp.net and the visual studio 2017 debugging does not work.The target framework is 461 since i have some projects in the same solution with older framework. The debugging hits  the older framework projects code, but not the core 2 project.

Comment: you probably have it in release mode, double check, that its in debug. i.e. no break point will be hit. if its not in debug.

Comment: Use Debug > Windows > Modules, to see what files are loaded during debug.

Comment: @Seabizkit yes , I checked before posting that  it was in debug mode ony.

Comment: i believe there have been a couple of sp for 2017, could you make ur your on the latest.